# Match order ID and invoice number with opencart vqmod

Tags: opencart

I have a opencart extension that matches invoice number and order ID, so it is easier for accounts. I have a problem where the Order ID is actually 1 number behind the invoice number and im not sure why. Here is the VQmod code

```
<file name="*/model/sale/order.php" error="skip">
    <operation error="skip">
        <search position="before"><![CDATA[
            // Send out any gift voucher mails
        ]]></search>
        <add trim="true"><![CDATA[
            if (empty($order_info['invoice_no']) && $data['order_status_id'] == $this->config->get('config_complete_status_id')) {
                $this->db->query("UPDATE `" . DB_PREFIX . "order` SET invoice_no = '" . (int)$order_id . "', invoice_prefix = '" . $this->db->escape($order_info['invoice_prefix']) . "' WHERE order_id = '" . (int)$order_id . "'");
            }
        ]]></add>
    </operation>
</file>

<file name="catalog/model/checkout/order.php" error="skip">
    <operation error="skip">
        <search position="before"><![CDATA[
            // Send out any gift voucher mails
        ]]></search>
        <add trim="true"><![CDATA[
            if (empty($order_info['invoice_no']) && $order_status_id == $this->config->get('config_complete_status_id')) {
                $this->db->query("UPDATE `" . DB_PREFIX . "order` SET invoice_no = '" . (int)$order_id . "', invoice_prefix = '" . $this->db->escape($order_info['invoice_prefix']) . "' WHERE order_id = '" . (int)$order_id . "'");
            }
        ]]></add>
    </operation>
</file>
```

Any Ideas?

Thank you

Comment: is it something that happens all the time, occasionally ore happened only once?

Comment: It's happening on every order. thanks

Comment: If it is a static phenomenon it means it is a fault at code level, i will try and analyse it, but if you want a quick fix simply decrease the int before inserting in your code above by 1 :D

Answer (score 1):

The reason for this is that simple:

- anytime You start a checkout process and walk through all the steps down to the last *Confirm* one **a new order is created** yet not visible (you can check in DB it is there with whole new ID with status set to `0`)
- after the order is confirmed (by payment method picked at the checkout process) it is being updated with a new status ID thus You can see the order **but it has no invoice number** so far
- now you may end up with starting but not finishing the checkout process many times - this creates blank orders that are never used

  - this step is nothing unusual as exactly at this *Confirm* step many customers are more cautious and walk through all the information carefully before paying. It is not a surprise that many of them cancel the checkout process at this very step because they just want for example add/remove some product (maybe because of weight-based shipping, there is unlimited reasons for this), checkout other option of some product, other variants, increase the number of products (and I could continue...). And voilà, a blank order is there while user made his changes to the cart and started a new checkout process :-)
- after you click on *Generate Invoice Number* in administration a new invoice ID is created and used for invoice number, thus You may have order ID 1126 with invoice number 201400994

Solution to this could be to use the order's ID for invoice number instead of the invoice's ID, but this may violate your country's tax laws as for example in Europe 90% of countries require the invoice numbers to be ordered, increasing, uninterrupted, solid line.

On the other hand having invoice numbers different from order numbers (IDs) is nothing strange nor nothing that customers aren't used to.